# adobe form date with javascript to be fixed when signed

Tags: javascript, date, adobe

i have an adobe form in which i use the following to have an auto updating date:

this.addScript("init", "this.getField(\"Today\").value = new Date();");

nevertheless this will update the date every time the file is opened. as the file has to be electronically signed, i would like to have the date unchangable after that. i tried by indicating that the signing should lock the date field, but this would just prevent other users from opening the field, the date would still update everytime. is there a way to put a condition in javascript that date will be fixed after a sgnature field is signed?
thanks a lot for help

bests
lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of locking a field after a document is signed, you could auto-fill the date only when the document is signed rather than when it is opened.

Instead of placing the script in the page level you can place it on the signature. The Digital Signature properties has specific Signed settings where you can run a script once the field is signed. Here is the script I am using:

```
var f = this.getField("Today");
f.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new Date());
```